# The free() function failed when calling out to free a char pointer that had stored a value

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, assign

i am learning somethings that about the dynamic memory allocations in C programming languages. When i was trying to write a program that describe as below:

> Write a function named duplicate that uses dynamic storage allocation to create a copy of a string. For example, the call
>
> > p = duplicate(str);
>
> would allocate space for a string of the same length as str, copy the contents of str into the new string, and return a pointer to it. Have duplicate return a null pointer if the memory allocation fails.

This is the exercise 2 of chapter17 in the book "C Programming Language, A Modern Approaches(2nd ver.)".

In my first attempt, i write my code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *duplicate(char* str){
    char* news=(char*)malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if(news==NULL){
        printf("Error: malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(news,str);
    return news;
}

int main(){
    char *str,*p;
    str="Hello world";
    p=duplicate(str);
    puts(p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

which run successfully.
But when i modify my code to call *free(str)* as below:

```
int main(){
    char *str,*p;
    str="Hello world";
    p=duplicate(str);
    free(str);
    puts(p);
    return 0;
}
```

it failed without any output and return an adnormal value.
In my book it doesn't mention anything about this problem but only giving some example about the free() function that use on the pointer that did not assign any value. I am curious that what's wrong with my code? If i want to use the free function, what is the proper way to use it and how can i free the pointer pointed to a memory that has assigned some value?

Comment: You cannot `free()` something that was not obtained from `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`). In your program you want: `p = duplicate(str); puts(p); free(p);`

Comment: You can `free(p)`.  You cannot (and do not need to) free `str`.

Comment: OT: *In C there is not need to cast `void`-pointers, as for example returned my `malloc()`*.

Comment: The code should not call `puts()` if `duplicate()` failed, will say if it returned `NULL`.

Comment: Doing `if (news == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed\n");
    } else {
    strcpy(news, str); }
    return news;` would be simpler and less error prone. Also it followed the nice pattern to have only *one* exit point per function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instruction

```c
str="Hello world";
```

assigns the constant string "Hello world" to str. It does not allocate the storage for the string with `malloc`. So you must not call `free` with `str` as argument. Only pointers obtained with a `malloc` may be passed to `free`.

"Hello world" is a constant string stored in a special location of the program. You must not free it and modify it.

Comment: where is that special location?